# How to pass body data in JSON format in API calling in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, api

```
dynamic body = {
  'doctor_availablity_done': StatusEnum.Yes.index.toString(),
  'emergency_call': emergencyCall,
  'weekends': {
    "days": selectedWeekendList.toString(),
    "time_period": {
      "morning": {
        "start_time": weekendMorningStart.value.toString(),
        "end_time": weekendMorningEnd.value.toString()
      },
      "afternoon": {
        "start_time": weekendAfternoonStart.value.toString(),
        "end_time": weekendAfternoonEnd.value.toString()
      },
      "evening": {
        "start_time": weekendEveningStart.value.toString(),
        "end_time": weekendEveningEnd.value.toString()
      },
      "night": {
        "start_time": weekendNightStart.value.toString(),
        "end_time": weekendNightStart.value.toString()
      }
    }
  }.toString(),
  'weekdays': {
    "days": selectedWeekdaysList.toString(),
    "time_period": {
      "morning": {
        "start_time": weekdaysMorningStart.value.toString(),
        "end_time": weekdaysMorningEnd.value.toString()
      },
      "afternoon": {
        "start_time": weekdaysAfternoonStart.value.toString(),
        "end_time": weekdaysAfternoonEnd.value.toString()
      },
      "evening": {
        "start_time": weekdaysEveningStart.value.toString(),
        "end_time": weekdaysEveningEnd.value.toString()
      },
      "night": {
        "start_time": weekdaysNightStart.value.toString(),
        "end_time": weekdaysNightStart.value.toString()
      }
    }
  }.toString(),
};
```

I want to pass this whole body content in JSON format. The above data is in string. How do I pass data in JSON. I'm trying to pass it in jsonEncode(body.toString()) but it throws error of invalid data.

var headers = {
'Authorization':
'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvdG90YWxoZWFsdGhzb2x1dGlvbnMub3JnLmluXC9tZWRpY2FsLWRldlwvYXBpXC9kb2N0b3JcL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNjYwMDQyMzg3LCJleHAiOjE2NjAxMjg3ODcsIm5iZiI6MTY2MDA0MjM4NywianRpIjoiMzI2Y2xsNzEybElYaktqSyIsInN1YiI6MTYzLCJwcnYiOiIyM2JkNWM4OTQ5ZjYwMGFkYjM5ZTcwMWM0MDA4NzJkYjdhNTk3NmY3In0.5FbSnY-tPQMdyNFxdWmPuxCmQAPUcutejWkKPJT3XTE'
};

```
var request = http.MultipartRequest(
    'POST',
    Uri.parse(
        url));
request.fields.addAll(jsonEncode(body));

request.headers.addAll(headers);

http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
} else {
  print(response.reasonPhrase);
}
```

Comment: Please add code that don't work and error message!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way

```
 var body = {};
  var weekends = {};
  var timePeriod = {};

  body["doctor_availablity_done"] = "1";
  body["emergency_call"] = "emergencyCall";

  weekends["days"] = "selectedWeekendList.toString()";
  timePeriod["morning"] = {"start_time": "ads", "end_time": "qsasds"};

  weekends["time_period"] = timePeriod;
  body["weekends"] = weekends;

  print(jsonEncode(body));
```

Other keys you can append. this is just sample.

EDIT

You don't need multipart request as you are not sending any files.

```
var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url) , headers: headers , body:  jsonEncode(body) );

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(response.body);
} else {
  print(response.body);
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried before this, but it's not supporting 
request.fields.addAll(jsonEncode(body));

It throws an error of 
Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'

Comment: @VrustiPatel : Are you making FormRequest or normal POST request please share that request so can provide solution according to it.

Comment: Yes, I have updated my question. Please look at that.

Comment: @VrustiPatel :  Please check  edited answer

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `toString()` on weekends and weekdays, and also not on the result, so like this

```
dynamic body = {
  'doctor_availablity_done': StatusEnum.Yes.index.toString(),
  'emergency_call': emergencyCall,
  'weekends': {
    "days": selectedWeekendList.toString(),
    "time_period": {
      "morning": {
        "start_time": weekendMorningStart.value.toString(),
        "end_time": weekendMorningEnd.value.toString()
      },
      "afternoon": {
        "start_time": weekendAfternoonStart.value.toString(),
        "end_time": weekendAfternoonEnd.value.toString()
      },
      "evening": {
        "start_time": weekendEveningStart.value.toString(),
        "end_time": weekendEveningEnd.value.toString()
      },
      "night": {
        "start_time": weekendNightStart.value.toString(),
        "end_time": weekendNightStart.value.toString()
      }
    }
  },
  'weekdays': {
    "days": selectedWeekdaysList.toString(),
    "time_period": {
      "morning": {
        "start_time": weekdaysMorningStart.value.toString(),
        "end_time": weekdaysMorningEnd.value.toString()
      },
      "afternoon": {
        "start_time": weekdaysAfternoonStart.value.toString(),
        "end_time": weekdaysAfternoonEnd.value.toString()
      },
      "evening": {
        "start_time": weekdaysEveningStart.value.toString(),
        "end_time": weekdaysEveningEnd.value.toString()
      },
      "night": {
        "start_time": weekdaysNightStart.value.toString(),
        "end_time": weekdaysNightStart.value.toString()
      }
    }
  },
};

String json = jsonEncode(body);
```

Comment: But it's not supporting String. request.fields.addAll(json);
It throws an error of Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'

Comment: @VrustiPatel I'm not aware of how `request.fields.addAll` works. But looks like it's not even expecting json. I'm not familiar with making requests like that. I merely demonstrated to you how to turn the data into json. Maybe it's a good idea to add your code to the question that shows how you make the request exactly

Comment: Ok. I have updated my question. please go through that.

Comment: @VrustiPatel I'm not really familiar with multi part request. A quick google makes me think that you can't add json bodies to those. Are you sure you need a multipart request? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65623460/how-to-send-json-object-with-http-post-multipart-request-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

```
  Object data = {
         "username": userName,
         "password": password,
 };


    Uri url = Uri.parse("url");
    final response = await http.post(url, body: data);
```

**or**

```
Map<String, dynamic> apiMap = new Map();
    apiMap.putIfAbsent("username", () => ""user_name);
    apiMap.putIfAbsent("pwd", () => "pwd));

    Uri url = Uri.parse("url");
    final response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(apiMap),);
```

Comment: If I pass data in Object then it throws me error of Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'

Comment: Object data = {
      "username": "userName",
      "password": "password",
    };

Comment: userName and password must be a string

Comment: request.fields.addAll(data)

Ofcourse it is string. But it is not supporting in request

Comment: now try the edited answer