# Flutter multipart/form-data send list of items

Tags: arrays, flutter, http, dart, multipartform-data

My using package [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http)

I have this method in my app to send post request with files. In my case I send files and also fields with dynamic values. I tried send `List<String>` but server (backend) return me error with message:

```
The seedlings field must be an array.
```

Example `seedlings` list value:

```
List<String> seedlings = ['Apple', 'Banana'];
```

**Code:**

```
Future post(String path, data) async {
  await _getToken();

  var url = '${ApiConstants.BASE_URL}$path';
  var uri = Uri.parse(url);
  var request = MultipartRequest('POST', uri);

  data.forEach((key, item) async {
    if (item == null) return null;
    if (item is File) {
      request.files.add(await MultipartFile.fromPath(
        'file',
        item.path,
      ));
    } else {
      request.fields[key] = item is num
        ? item.toString()
        : item is List
            ? item.toString()
            : item;
    }
  });

  request.headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json';
  request.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';

  var response = await request.send();
}
```

In my case all fields sent to server except fields with `list` of values like `array`

Comment: You have to use a for loop and assign indexes for list

Answer (score 2):

This might be old, but you can easily do this by adding the array items into a form data array

```dart
final FormData formData = FormData({});

// Add all normal string request body data
formData.fields.add(MapEntry("name", "Olayemii"));    
formData.fields.add(MapEntry("age", 99));   

// Add all files request body data
formData.files.add(MapEntry("profile_photo", file));


// Add the array item 
List<String> seedlings = ['Apple', 'Banana'];

seedlings.forEach((element) {
    formData.fields.add(MapEntry("seedlings[]", element.toString()));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer for this which I have posted in another similar question. I'll just put the code snippet here.

```
final request = http.MultipartRequest('Post', uri);
List<String> ManageTagModel = ['xx', 'yy', 'zz'];
for (String item in ManageTagModel) {
    request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromString('manage_tag_model', item));
}
```

Basically you have to add the list as files with `fromString()` method.
Find the original answer here-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66318541/7337717